# Linux Building - CROSS_COMPILE BusyBox: limits.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, busybox

i'm building linux from source as shown in this article

[diy-build-custom-minimal-linux-distribution-source](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/diy-build-custom-minimal-linux-distribution-source)

I built the tool-chain

- linux-api-header
- binutils
- gcc
- glibc

and the next step is building BusyBox,

```
CROSS_COMPILE="i686-x-linux-gnu"
PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/build/tools/bin"
        
make CROSS_COMPILE="${CROSS_COMPILE}-" defconfig 
make CROSS_COMPILE="${CROSS_COMPILE}-"
```

resulting in this error

```
i686-x-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include-fixed/limits.h:194:15: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
```

where limits.h is a file included in the linux headers, located in /usr/includes and /build/usr/includes (where /build is the directory with the linux image built)

How i can specify to BusyBox to search for the headers in the /build root, and not in the pc's /? or should be in the gcc of the toolchain?

Comment: You should have installed the Kernel Headers.

Comment: I think I did it, make ARCH=$ARCH INSTALL_HDR_PATH=dest headers_install and then copying to the target directory.  Is it that what you mean?